# How do I check composite ID exists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with 3 columns in its primary key. How do I check that a particular ID exists?

I know for 1 primary key... but I don't know for many!

```
public bool Check(string id)
{
    return (from eee in Db.table where eee.id == id select eee).Any();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have 1 id or a 3-part compound key, or 3 tables with the primary key possibly in? or ...?

Comment: How a table can contain 3 primary keys....... is it combination of three fields....

Comment: It can't, which is why I ask what he means.

Comment: composite primary key do exist...

Comment: Yes, but that is 1 primary key containing 3 columns. And he's asking how to check if 1 id exists. I fail to see how that is even possible if you have spread out the key over 3 columns and want to check for 1 value.

Comment: Is it linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 6):

if you have a composite key

```
public bool Check(string key1, string key2, string key3) {
  return Db.table.Any(x => x.key1== key1 && x.key2 == key2 && x.key3 == key3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check all the three rows - like:

```
public bool Check(string id, string id2, string id3)
{
       return (from eee in Db.table where eee.id == id select && eee.id2 == id2 select && eee.id3 == id3 select eee).Any();
}
```

Comment: Should you not pass id2 and id3 also as method parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Pass all of your IDs to your function and try this code ,

```
public bool Check(string id ,string id_2 , string id_3)
{
   return (from eee in Db.table where eee.id == id select && eee.id_2 == id_2 select && eee.id_3 == id_3 select eee).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have composite key in your table and you are using Entity Framework then you can use [DbSet.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method which accepts list of composite primary key values:

```
return db.table.Find(key1, key2) != null;
```

Comment: @zey thanks! It worth noting, that this solution has two benefits - it's more readable, and it will not query database if entity is already in context, but it also have drawback - it will query all fields of entity from database.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be...

```
public bool IsCompositeKey(string id, string id2, string id3)
{
    return (from eee in Db.table where eee.id == id select && eee.id2 == id2 select && eee.id3 == id3 select eee).Any();
}
```